# Java: Extract json values as individuals

Tags: java, json

I have this json in java:

```
jsonObj = {"ps":["2.16.840.1.113883.6.1","LOINC","2.34"]}
```

`jsonObj` is response from an API, so I have it as jsonObject and I don't read it from any file.

Is there an easy way to extract all the values as individuals like `jsonObj [1]`?

Comment: Of course you can. Either parse the json to a pojo or to a combination of maps (representing objects) and lists (representing arrays) and access the values individually. The syntax would be somewhat different though (e.g. like `parsedObject.getPs()[1]`)

Comment: What do you expect jsonObj[1] returns? "LOINC"?

Comment: @zuno Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may Use Gson parsing library as below :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// 1. JSON to Java object, read it from a file.
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\file.json"), Staff.class);

// 2. JSON to Java object, read it from a Json String.
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'mkyong'}";
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Staff.class);

// JSON to JsonElement, convert to String later.
JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\file.json"), JsonElement.class);
    String result = gson.toJson(json);


Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = "{\"userId\":\"1\",\"userName\":\"Yasir\"}";
User user= gson.fromJson(jsonInString, User.class);
```

or simply use:

example

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(your_json_response_string);
String IMEICheckResponse  = object.getString("getIMEIResult");
```

for Array use :

```
//getting whole json string
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

//extracting data array from json string
JSONArray ja_data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
int length = jsonObj .length();
```

Comment: In `JSONArray ja_data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data")` what is `data`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a library to deserialize your JSON in a Java Object.
Libraries like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), [Genson](https://owlike.github.io/genson/) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).
Once you transform the json in a object, it will have a property called "ps" that will be an array (or a List)